# How do I suppress the output of a .each loop on an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've searched so, and can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem.
I'm working through Michael Hartle's RoR tutorial and I've hit an oddity. I've been following his instructions to the T, except where Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1 differ from the older versions he's working with.
In returning the errors if a user attempts to sign up with bad data, he's created an erb file for inclusion titled, _error_messages.html.erb
Here is the file's code:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
 <div class="error_explanation round padding_10">
   <h3 class="error_explanation">
     <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
     prohibited this user from being saved:
   </h3>
   <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
   <ul>
   <%= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
   <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>
<br />
```

now, when he executes this code, he gets exactly what you'd expect. An unordered list of errors as is specified by the @user object after an invalid User.new attempt.

However, the output I'm getting - the actual HTML - is this:

```
<div class="error_explanation round padding_10">
   <h3 class="error_explanation">
     2 errors
     prohibited this user from being saved:
   </h3>
   <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
   <ul>

     <li>Password can&#39;t be blank</li>

     <li>Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)</li>
[&quot;Password can&#39;t be blank&quot;, &quot;Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)&quot;]   </ul>
 </div>
<br />
```

as you can see, I'm getting the expected output with an added bonus. The full array of errors is being output as well: `[&quot;Password can&#39;t be blank&quot;, &quot;Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)&quot;]`

I've looked through some of the suggestions for suppression - and I've tried every permutation I can think of, such as:

```
@user.errors.full_messages.each;nil do |msg|
#and
@user.errors.full_messages.each do;nil |msg|
#and
@user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|;nil
#and
end;nil
```

I wasn't surprised to find that there were all syntactically incorrect.
What am I missing? Why is the full array dumping?
Thank you for anyone who lends a hand - this is fairly frustrating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `=` from the line `<%= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>`. That's it.